# Trying to highlight instances in one column where the value is duplicated in another column

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting

This question has been raised on here before, but I find that I am not doing something right, as my knowledge of excel is quite poor.

I have two lists of data. List one is a very long list of 650 numerical items (in the form of xx-xxxx) and the second list is about half the size with similar numerical items in the same format. I want to highlight cells in list one where the values are present in list two. From what I read on this website people were using vlookup, but I do not know how to use vlookup in the slightest and could not get it to work.

If someone could walk me through the process step by step it would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `do not know how to use vlookup in the slightest and could not get it to work` What did you try?

Comment: I would use countif instead.

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting can be done with conditional formatting in this case. Let's assume that the long list is in column A, the short list is in column B.

Select all the data in column A with the active cell in A1.

On the Home ribbon click Conditional Formatting > New Rule > use a formula to determine ...

Enter this formula

```
=COUNTIF($B:$B,A1)
```

and select a format, for example a colored fill. Note that there are no $ signs in the A1 cell reference.

[image]

Comment: In that case, finish the paperwork and accept my post as the answer, so others can find it too. If you don't know how to accept an answer, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You could use =IF(COUNTIF($C$3:$C$9,E3)>0,COUNTIF($C$3:$C$9,E3),"") but use that in the conditional formatting.

[image]